# Write a loop that finds a value and returns a color

Tags: javascript, loops, google-visualization

I am trying to get a Google Column Chart to change the column color when the values are changed. So when the value is '5' the column would be red, if it's '1' then it would be green.

I can't get this to work. I know it's something with the loop, but I am a complete beginner when it comes to loops. Basically I want the second value in a data row (the number) to trigger a color change from the myColors variable...

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

     function drawChart1() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();        
          data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
          data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
          data.addRow(['Environmental', 2, slicesColor]);
          data.addRow(['Best Available Data', 5, slicesColor]);
          data.addRow(['Approach Roadways', 4, slicesColor]);
          data.addRow(['Structure', 1, slicesColor]);
          data.addRow(['Hydraulics', 5, slicesColor]);
          data.addRow(['Geotechnical', 3, slicesColor]);

        var myColors = { '1' : 'green', '2': '#000000', '3': 'yellow', '4': 'orange', '5': 'red'  };

        var slicesColor = {};

        for( var i=0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
          slicesColor[i] = {color: myColors[data.getValue(i, 0)] };
        }

        var options = {
          legend: { position: "none" },
          slices: slicesColor,
          title: 'Risk Categories'
        }

            // Create and draw the visualization.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);   

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelmix/bvpmv8d6/3/

I found this example with another chart library, but I don't know how that would translate to work with the Google charts API:
http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/live_column/

Comment: I have not tested your code, and have not worked with this DataTable, but you might want to check that data.getValue(i, 0); is correct. Maybe it should be data.getValue(i, 1); (i representing the row, 1 representing the column)

Comment: Yes I did try that and it did not work for me. I think that it's something to do with the myColors variable. I think that I am not connecting those values to the data values correctly.

Comment: What happens if you replace myColors[data.getValue(i, 0)] with, say, 'red'. Do this work (all get this color)?

Comment: You may need to add ' surrounding the number you get back from getValue if this works. So result is e.g. myColors['1'] instead of myColors[1]

Comment: Still not working for me. I tried your suggestions as well as bunch of other scenarios and still nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For coloring columns of `google.visualization.ColumnChart class` [style role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) is intended. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#coloring-columns):

> The style role lets your control several aspects of column appearance
>   with CSS-like declarations:
>
> - color
> - opacity
> - fill-color
> - fill-opacity
> - stroke-color
> - stroke-opacity
> - stroke-width

You could replace:

```
for( var i=0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
   slicesColor[i] = {color: myColors[data.getValue(i, 0)] };
}
```

with

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows() ; i++) {
    var key = data.getValue(i, 1);
    data.setValue(i, 2, 'color:' + myColors[key]);
}
```

**Example**

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

function drawChart1() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
    data.addRow(['Environmental', 2, null]);
    data.addRow(['Best Available Data', 5, null]);
    data.addRow(['Approach Roadways', 4, null]);
    data.addRow(['Structure', 1, null]);
    data.addRow(['Hydraulics', 5, null]);
    data.addRow(['Geotechnical', 3, null]);

    var myColors = { '1': 'green', '2': '#000000', '3': 'yellow', '4': 'orange', '5': 'red' };

    var slicesColor = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows() ; i++) {
        var key = data.getValue(i, 1);
        data.setValue(i, 2, 'color:' + myColors[key]);
    }

    var options = {
        legend: { position: "none" },
        //slices: slicesColor,
        title: 'Risk Categories'
    }

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```